# PHP OpenSSL Encrypt vs Command Line Encypt

Tags: php, pyopenssl

I've been having some issues with the builtin methods for PHP OpenSSL. I'm attempting to narrow down the issue by trying different methods. I'm trying the following:

```
$input = "this is a test string";
$opensslCommand = "echo \"{$input}\" | openssl enc -AES-128-CBC -a -nosalt -K " . bin2hex($hashing_secret) . " -iv ". bin2hex($iv);

$first = openssl_encrypt($input, "AES-128-CBC", $hashing_secret, 0, $iv);
$second = exec($opensslCommand);

print(urlencode($first) . "<br/>");
print(urlencode($second) . "<br/>");
```

however, the output of the above is:

```
hn%2FZkGKl9EQ7XgFFytcPkTPxJST2jCKEVDoojmkz8xs%3D
hn%2FZkGKl9EQ7XgFFytcPkdQESeAPqlFNwJivth28m9o%3D
```

As you can see, they start to diverge in the middle of the output. Do I have the configuration wrong for either the builtin or the command line?

3rd party edit:
Making more sense of the output:

Base64 encoded:
`hn/ZkGKl9EQ7XgFFytcPkTPxJST2jCKEVDoojmkz8xs=`
`hn/ZkGKl9EQ7XgFFytcPkdQESeAPqlFNwJivth28m9o=`

In hex:
`867FD990 62A5F444 3B5E0145 CAD70F91 33F12524 F68C2284 543A288E 6933F31B`
`867FD990 62A5F444 3B5E0145 CAD70F91 D40449E0 0FAA514D C098AFB6 1DBC9BDA`

Comment: Examining the binary it is clear that the first 16-bytes are the first block and identical, the second 16-bytes are the second block and differ. So this may be an encryption mode issue of that the end portion of the data to be encrypted is different.

Comment: An easy online way to check encryption is [AES Calculator](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc) by Cryptomathic. There are other calculators for other algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is the culprit here. There's a certain parameter you can use with echo to suppress the newline it appends to its input string: `-n`. Turns out that was getting piped along with my input into openssl.

```
$opensslCommand = "echo -n \"{$input}\" | openssl enc -AES-128-CBC -a -nosalt -K " . bin2hex($hashing_secret) . " -iv ". bin2hex($iv);
```

is the correct command